# Getting Ruby syntax straight

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to teach myself Ruby and Ruby on Rails. Can someone give me some quick pointers on this code from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Questions:

1. Sometimes the code uses `<%` and sometimes uses `<%=`. When do I use either of these?
2. What exactly does `@` mean in Ruby and when is is used?
3. Besides for the HTML, is all of Ruby code, or there some new code/syntax which Ruby on Rails introduces?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247480/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319347/variables-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: all those questions are answered numerous times. do you mind using google or stackoverflow's search capabilities?

Comment: These are all very general questions about basic rails functionality, so you're not likely to get a useful answer here. You just need to work your way through a few tutorials and read a few books on Ruby. Rails does introduce a lot of methods and classes, but aside from html, css, and javascript, the syntax is all Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `<%=` outputs the result of the expression to the page. `<%` just evaluates it.
2. `@` indicates an instance variable in a class. In Rails, it's also how you expose a controller variable to it's view.
3. Rails does not add any new syntax to Ruby, although there are some conventions which may look different from 'traditional' Ruby code.