# Ruby on rails forms_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello guys I am new to Ruby . I am try to create form with form builder 
What is difference between

```
<%=form_for @post %>
```

and

```
<%=form_for :post %>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) creates an instance of the [form builder object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html):

> A FormBuilder object is associated with a particular model object and
>   allows you to generate fields associated with the model object. The
>   FormBuilder object is yielded when using form_for or fields_for

---

`@post` is an instance variable. `:post` isn't

This means that when you load a `<%= form_for @post %>`, you're populating the form builder object with data from the instance (allowing Rails to maintain the data when you have errors etc)

If you're unsure about [`@instance_variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319347/variables-in-ruby-on-rails) in Ruby, you might want to check out the Ruby On Rails [beginners' guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: It can be a lot of things (I can't give a concise answer unfortunately). Here's a really good reference for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341837/understanding-symbols-in-ruby

Comment: I only know `:symbols` are used mainly to determine arguments for Rails methods (I.E `<%= form_for @post, method: :post %>`

Comment: `:post` is just namespace for a future object and also html <form> namespace. `@post` is existing instance variables with Post properties.

Answer (score 0):

if you are use symbol :post like

```
<%=form_for :post %>
```

then it create

```
<form action="/posts" method="post">
```

if you are use instance @post like

```
<%=form_for @post %>
```

then it create

```
 <form action="/posts/create" class="class_name" id="id_name" method="post">
```

Comment: I think, When the model is represented by a string or symbol, if the :url option is not specified, by default the form will be sent back to the current url